# GeoCoder AsyncTask doesn't update TextView in background

Tags: android, android-asynctask, geocoding, android-maps

Scenario:

So what I have done so far is Created an AsyncTask to handle my GeoCoder that updates every 3 min (for testing purposes). Then I set up a TimerTask that shows a toast message with the users current Address every 4 minutes. (TimerTasks not included in code)

So heres the problem:

When I am in my app, everything is fine, however when my app is running in the background, the Toast messages stay stuck at whatever address the app was last set at before I exited my app. I know for sure that the AsyncTask does run in the background (Checked LogCats) and it seems like everything is running in the background fine, I just cant display the current address on my Toast.

All thoughts and inputs will be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
 public class statuspage extends MapActivity {

LocationManager locationManager;
MapView mapView;
Criteria criteria;
Location location;
Geocoder gc;
Address address;

String bestProvider;
String LOCATION_SERVICE = "location";
String addressString = "Searching for Nearest Address";
StringBuilder sb;

private MapController mapController;
private MyLocationOverlay myLocation;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.statuspage);

    // Get Mapping Controllers etc //
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(17);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // Add the MyLocationOverlay //
    myLocation = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocation);
    myLocation.enableCompass();
    myLocation.enableMyLocation();

    // Animates the map to GPS Position //
    myLocation.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mapController.animateTo(myLocation.getMyLocation());

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

    // Location Manager Intiation
    locationManager = (LocationManager) statuspage.this
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    criteria = new Criteria();

    // More accurate, GPS fix.
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); // More accurate, GPS fix.
    bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    updateWithNewLocation(location);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 60000, 10,
            locationListener); // 1800000 = 30 Min

    return false;
}

class GeoCoder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String lat = "Acquiring";
    String lng = "Acquiring";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (location != null) {

            /**
             * double latitude = myLocation.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6();
             * double longitude =
             * myLocation.getMyLocation().getLongitudeE6();
             */

            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            lat = "" + latitude;
            lng = "" + longitude;

            // gc = new Geocoder(statuspage.this, Locale.getDefault());
            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                    Locale.getDefault());
            try {

                List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude,
                        longitude, 1);

                sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                    address = addresses.get(0);

                    int noOfMaxAddressLine = address
                            .getMaxAddressLineIndex();
                    if (noOfMaxAddressLine > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < address
                                .getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                            sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append(
                                    "\n");
                        }
                        addressString = sb.toString();

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                addressString = "Sorry, we are trying to find information about this location";
            }

        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        TextView scrollview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);

        // Latitude and Longitude TextView
        TextView etlongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etlongitude);
        TextView etlatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etlatitude);

        // TextView to display GeoCoder Address
        scrollview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        scrollview.setText("Your location:" + "\n"
                + "(Accurate to 500 meters)" + "\n" + (addressString));

        Log.d("Address", (addressString));

        // Latitude and Longitude TextView Display Coordinates //
        etlongitude.setText(lng);
        etlatitude.setText(lat);

        // Log.d("GeoCoder", "In-Task");

        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using an assync task you cant update the UI in background.Its impossible to connect the UI from inside thread thats from background.The only way to connect the UI is to use the onPostExecute().And use this onPostExecute() function to update the UI.try sending messages from the background and do the UI stuff on the postexecute by checking the messages.This will help you for sure.

Comment: Thanks sree, Ill try to do some research on this. Could you give me a link that can explain this in more details?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. If I stay on the current activity, no problem, but if I leave the activity while `doInBackgroud` is running, `onPostExecute` will exit on the Toast line.

To resolve the problem, you have to use a handler :
In the class

```
private static final int TOAST  = 0;
private Handler mHandler = null;
```

In `OnCreate()`

```
// Creation of the handler to display Toasts
if (mHandler == null) {
    mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message _msg) {
            switch (_msg.what) {
            case TOAST:
            Toast.makeText(ServerTabHost.this, (String)_msg.obj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
            default : break;
        }
        super.handleMessage(_msg);
        }
    };
}
```

In `onPostExecute()`

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.what = TOAST;
msg.obj = "my toast message";
mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

In your code it looks like this :

```
public class statuspage extends MapActivity {

// These two lines are for the handler
private static final int TOAST  = 0;
private Handler mHandler = null;

LocationManager locationManager;
MapView mapView;
Criteria criteria;
Location location;
Geocoder gc;
Address address;

String bestProvider;
String LOCATION_SERVICE = "location";
String addressString = "Searching for Nearest Address";
StringBuilder sb;

private MapController mapController;
private MyLocationOverlay myLocation;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.statuspage);

    // Get Mapping Controllers etc //
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(17);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // Add the MyLocationOverlay //
    myLocation = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocation);
    myLocation.enableCompass();
    myLocation.enableMyLocation();

    // Animates the map to GPS Position //
    myLocation.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mapController.animateTo(myLocation.getMyLocation());

        }
    });

    // Creation of the handler to display Toasts
    if (mHandler == null) {
        mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message _msg) {
            switch (_msg.what) {
                case TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(ServerTabHost.this, (String)_msg.obj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
                default : break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(_msg);
            }
        };
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

    // Location Manager Intiation
    locationManager = (LocationManager) statuspage.this
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    criteria = new Criteria();

    // More accurate, GPS fix.
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); // More accurate, GPS fix.
    bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    updateWithNewLocation(location);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 60000, 10,
            locationListener); // 1800000 = 30 Min

    return false;
}

class GeoCoder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String lat = "Acquiring";
    String lng = "Acquiring";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (location != null) {

            /**
             * double latitude = myLocation.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6();
             * double longitude =
             * myLocation.getMyLocation().getLongitudeE6();
             */

            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            lat = "" + latitude;
            lng = "" + longitude;

            // gc = new Geocoder(statuspage.this, Locale.getDefault());
            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                    Locale.getDefault());
            try {

                List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude,
                        longitude, 1);

                sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                    address = addresses.get(0);

                    int noOfMaxAddressLine = address
                            .getMaxAddressLineIndex();
                    if (noOfMaxAddressLine > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < address
                                .getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                            sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append(
                                    "\n");
                        }
                        addressString = sb.toString();

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                addressString = "Sorry, we are trying to find information about this location";
            }

        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // Sending the Toast message through the handler
        Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = TOAST;
    msg.obj = "My toast message";
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        TextView scrollview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);

        // Latitude and Longitude TextView
        TextView etlongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etlongitude);
        TextView etlatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etlatitude);

        // TextView to display GeoCoder Address
        scrollview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        scrollview.setText("Your location:" + "\n"
                + "(Accurate to 500 meters)" + "\n" + (addressString));

        Log.d("Address", (addressString));

        // Latitude and Longitude TextView Display Coordinates //
        etlongitude.setText(lng);
        etlatitude.setText(lat);

        // Log.d("GeoCoder", "In-Task");

        return;
    }
```

Personally, I was in a Fragment so I had to create the handler in the host activity and then pass it in the fragment constructor.

Comment: I've never dealt with Handlers before. Thank you for the help and guidance. I am researching handlers now to understand it better. So far, what you have suggested seems to be working to my liking. Thanks Elasticboy!

Comment: Sorry if my question was a little misleading. The toast messages appear fine, its just when I am not in my app (browsing the web for example) my toast message will stay stuck at the address that it provided for me when I was in my current activity and it will keep showing me that same address until I go back into my app. The address does not get updated until I got back into my Activity.

Comment: So, the toast message is displayed but with an obsolete information, is that it ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think I might have got it working by using runOnUiThread inside my AsyncTask. I am testing it as we speak. If you have any other thoughts or additional information, please share!

Comment: I don't see the Toast message call in the code you posted. Can you post this part ? That could help me understand why it does not work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to Add the Toast Code. I have my Toast set up also on a TimerTask. I was able to fix my problem by using runOnUiThread and all is well now. Thanks for your support!